# Facebook App using Qooxdoo or any other RIA Framework

Tags: facebook, ria, qooxdoo

is it possible to create a UI for a facebook app using qooxdoo or anything similar?

Thx, Sven Koluem

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Javascript frameworks with Facebook, it is a little bit tricky but possible. If you use qooxdoo or any other library in iframe, there is no problem. But if you want to use them in native code, then you have problems.

Here is a link about using Jquery in Facebook apps:
http://userscripts.org/topics/23292?page=1#posts-103426